# How to give gradient on view in at top , bottom and transparent center?

Tags: java, android, xml, gradient

[image: Image like this]

I want to give gradient to this view like around 10% of imageview at top , transparent center with 70% and 30% gradient at the bottom.
How i can achieve this

Comment: Look at [this](https://chiuki.github.io/android-shaders-filters/#/5) maybe will help

Comment: Just have a gradient View over `ViewPager`..

Comment: @ADM but how can i give gradient in percents ..that is my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of just using a `shape` with a `gradient` use a `layer-list` with 2 `gradients` with specified height for each

API 21

The `android:bottom` , `android:top` attributes represent the padding for the layer list, change these to change the percentage of the gradient to show

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:bottom="690dp"
    android:gravity="top">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <gradient
            android:angle="270"
            android:type="linear"
            android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
            android:startColor="#000000" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:top="610dp"
    android:gravity="bottom">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <gradient
            android:angle="270"
            android:type="linear"
            android:endColor="#000000"
            android:startColor="@android:color/transparent" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

If your `minSDK` is 23+ then it's more easier to specify the `height` for each layer type

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:height="40dp"
    android:gravity="top">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:angle="270"
            android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
            android:startColor="#000000"
            android:type="linear" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:height="70dp"
    android:gravity="bottom">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:angle="270"
            android:endColor="#000000"
            android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
            android:type="linear" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Then just apply this as the `background` of your `ViewPager`

Try this out, hope this solves your issue

Comment: why you are using bottom = 690dp?

Comment: Because that's the padding from `bottom` for the top gradient.
We want the gradient to be XXdp padded away from the parent's bottom.
You should customize that value depending on your parent view `height`

Comment: WILL CHECK and get back to you

Answer (score 1):

top_gradient:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:centerColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:centerY="0.1"
        android:startColor="#000000" />
</shape>
```

bottom_gradient:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:centerColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:centerY="0.3"
        android:startColor="#000000" />
</shape>
```

background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg2" />
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

gradient.xml

```
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#00000000"
        android:centerColor="#00000000"
        android:endColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
        android:angle="270"
        android:centerY="0.7"
        android:dither="true"
        android:type="linear"
        />
</shape>
```

layout.xml:

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottomConstraint"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                style="@style/TextStyleNormal.Large.Bold.White"
                android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/padding_large"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_medium"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bottomConstraint"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/bottomConstraint"
                tools:text="System Solution to Online Education:
Look To Northeast communal." />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This will have transparent view but in bottom the gradient would be dark .

Comment: what about in top and how much bottom gradient will be there

Comment: It will depend where you re applying gradient for example: if you see the layout given above the constraint layout has fixed height   100dp inside that layout  i have added gradient as background . See the gradient start color is transparent and the end color is black

Comment: look at the image , i want 10% gradient on top and 30% of gradient at bottom

Comment: will check and then will let you know

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it like this

gradient_top.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
    android:startColor="#2B3135"
    android:centerColor="#2B3135"
    android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:angle="270"
    android:centerY="0.1"
    />
</shape>
```

gradient_bottom.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
    android:startColor="#2B3135"
    android:centerColor="#2B3135"
    android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:angle="90"
    android:centerY="0.3"
    />
</shape>
```

layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ib"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_top"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_bottom"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```